# Python file parsing, can't catch strings in new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Parsing a large text file with 56,900 book titles with authors and a etext no.
Trying to find the authors. By parsing the file.
 The file is a like this:

```
TITLE and AUTHOR                                                     ETEXT NO.

Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger

The Vicar of Morwenstow, by Sabine Baring-Gould                          56899
 [Subtitle: Being a Life of Robert Stephen Hawker, M.A.]

Raamatun tutkisteluja IV, mennessä Charles T. Russell                    56898
 [Subtitle: Harmagedonin taistelu]
 [Language: Finnish]

Raamatun tutkisteluja III, mennessä Charles T. Russell                   56897
 [Subtitle: Tulkoon valtakuntasi]
 [Language: Finnish]

Tom Thatcher's Fortune, by Horatio Alger, Jr.                            56896

A Yankee Flier in the Far East, by Al Avery                              56895
 and George Rutherford Montgomery
 [Illustrator: Paul Laune]

Nancy Brandon's Mystery, by Lillian Garis                                56894

Nervous Ills, by Boris Sidis                                             56893
 [Subtitle: Their Cause and Cure]

Pensées sans langage, par Francis Picabia                                56892
 [Language: French]

Helon's Pilgrimage to Jerusalem, Volume 2 of 2, by Frederick Strauss     56891
 [Subtitle: A picture of Judaism, in the century
  which preceded the advent of our Savior]

Fra Tommaso Campanella, Vol. 1, di Luigi Amabile                         56890
 [Subtitle: la sua congiura, i suoi processi e la sua pazzia]
 [Language: Italian]

The Blue Star, by Fletcher Pratt                                         56889

Importanza e risultati degli incrociamenti in avicoltura,                56888
 di Teodoro Pascal
 [Language: Italian]

The Junior Classics, Volume 3: Tales from Greece and Rome, by Various    56887


~ ~ ~ ~ Posting Dates for the below eBooks:  1 Mar 2018 to 31 Mar 2018 ~ ~ ~ ~

TITLE and AUTHOR                                                     ETEXT NO.

The American Missionary, Volume 41, No. 1, January, 1887, by Various     56886

Morganin miljoonat, mennessä Sven Elvestad                               56885
 [Author a.k.a. Stein Riverton]
 [Subtitle: Salapoliisiromaani]
 [Language: Finnish]

"Trip to the Sunny South" in March, 1885, by L. S. D                     56884

Balaam and His Master, by Joel Chandler Harris                           56883
 [Subtitle: and Other Sketches and Stories]

Susien saaliina, mennessä Jack London                                    56882
 [Language: Finnish]

Forged Egyptian Antiquities, by T. G. Wakeling                           56881

The Secret Doctrine, Vol. 3 of 4, by Helena Petrovna Blavatsky           56880
 [Subtitle: Third Edition]

No Posting                                                               56879
```

Author name usually starts after "by" or when there is no "by" in line then author name starts after a comma ","...However the "," can be a part of the title if the line has a by.
So, I parsed it for by first then for comma.

Here is what I tried:

```
def search_by_author():

    fhand = open('GUTINDEX.ALL')
    print("Search by Author:")

    for line in fhand:
        if not line.startswith(" [") and not line.startswith("TITLE"):
            if not line.startswith("~"):
                words = line.rstrip()
                words = line.lstrip()
                words = words[:-6] 
                if ", by" in words:

                    words = words[words.find(', by'):]
                    words = words[5:]
                    print (words)

                else:
                    words = words[words.find(', '):]
                    words = words[5:]
                    if "," in words:
                        words = words[words.find(', '):]
                        if words.startswith(','):
                            words =words[words.find(','):]
                            print (words)
                        else:
                            print (words)
                    else:
                        print (words)
                if " by" in words:
                    words = words[words.find('by')]
                    print(words)

search_by_author()
```

However it can't seem to find the author name for lines like

```
Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are _not_ parsing a Python file, do you?

Comment: No, a text file

Comment: Then edit your confusing question title please: it's not Python file parsing but text file parsing.

Comment: you have stripped the line and  then searching for ` by` , in `if " by" in words:` , is that correct ?

Comment: also ` words = line.rstrip(),  words = line.lstrip()` , what is this ??

Comment: Yes...lstrip() and rstrip() is to clear the black spaces left and right

Comment: The second statement will assign a value to `words`, and what was assigned to `words` in the first statement will be lost, so in effect, you don't do `rstrip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your file, info about a book can be spread across multiple lines. There is a blank line after each book info. I used that to gather all info about a book and then parse it to get the author info.

```
import re

def search_by_author():

    fhand = open('GUTINDEX.ALL')
    book_info = ''

    for line in fhand:
        line = line.rstrip()

        if (line.startswith('TITLE') or line.startswith('~')):
            continue

        if (len(line) == 0):
            # remove info in square bracket from book_info
            book_info = re.sub(r'\[.*$', '', book_info)

            if ('by ' in book_info):
                tokens = book_info.split('by ')
            else:
                tokens = book_info.split(',')

            if (len(tokens) > 1):
                authors = tokens[-1].strip()
                print(authors)

            book_info = ''

        else:
            # remove ETEXT NO. from line
            line = re.sub(r'\d+$', '', line)
            book_info +=  ' ' + line.rstrip()


search_by_author()
```

Output:

```
Robert Lloyd Praeger
Sabine Baring-Gould
mennessä Charles T. Russell
mennessä Charles T. Russell
Horatio Alger, Jr.
Al Avery  and George Rutherford Montgomery
Lillian Garis
Boris Sidis
par Francis Picabia
Frederick Strauss
di Luigi Amabile
Fletcher Pratt
di Teodoro Pascal
Various
Various
mennessä Sven Elvestad
L. S. D
Joel Chandler Harris
mennessä Jack London
T. G. Wakeling
Helena Petrovna Blavatsky
```